# How to use ExifInterface with base64

Tags: android, image-processing

I can get image rotation by ExifInterface

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(filename);
orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);
```

But it only accpets file path

My image file is a base64 string

If I don't want to write the image to disk, how to use ExifInterface with base64 string?

Answer (score 0):

ExifInterface will not handle base64 encoded images in Strings. Or base64 encoded images in files. It will not even handle image files which are put in a byte array or which can be read from a stream. You are out of luck.